# a few good men english question

Tags: american-english

Sorry, what does "Would it be so that it never sees the inside of a courtroom" in this context? I don't understand what it means. Please tell me. thank you.

-- excerpt from the movie --
  Why does a junior grade with six 
                         months experience and a track record 
                         for plea bargaining get assigned a 
                         murder case?
                              (beat)
                         Would it be so that it never sees 
                         the inside of a courtroom?

Comment: Would it (the situation outlined in the first sentence) be so that it (the case) never comes to court?

Comment: Could it be that this is being done so that the case never comes to trial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it be so that it never sees the inside of a courtroom

could be said, in more words:

> Would it be so the case is never brought to trial , but settled before the trial?

The writers of this motion picture script seem to be assuming that most viewers will understand that a defendant may negotiate by offering a guilty plea in return for less severe punishment,  prior to trial.

Such an arrangement is often referred to as "plea bargaining"  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plea_bargain)